# How to make UIPageViewController transition behaviour like the interactive pop transition style in IOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

In IOS7, when we pan on the screen edge to right, it will return the previous view controller. Also the transition is interactive, i.e., when we stop panning right, or panning distance is too short, the transition will not finished.

After reading others' blog, I know it can be called `interactive pop transition`.

The UIPageViewController contains many content ViewControllers, when swiping/panning the screen, we can view the different view controller, but the transition is too simple for me.

And following is my question:

I want to make the transition style in UIPageViewController like the mentioned above (interactive pop transition). They are difference in many ways, for example the previous view controller should be little darker.

And I do not want to custom my own transition style in [this way](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/view-controller-transitions.html), I just want to use the `interactive pop transition in IOS7 default offered`.

So maybe I should take some binding work? or assign some transition action in some where?

Comment: @rdelmar thanks, but I am really quite like the style of the `interactive pop transition`, is there any way I can achieve the same style in my custom transition?

Answer (score 0):

You should search for the style of `interactive pop transition`, and follow this custom your own transition.